# Cannot set property 'pagination' of undefined

Tags: jhipster

I cannot set the property 'pagination' of undefined.
I get the following error:

> Error while parsing applications and entities from the JDL TypeError:
>   Cannot set property 'pagination' of undefined.

I ran

```
jhipster import-jdl ./src/main/scripts/test.jh --debug
```

but the generator sent me back to the above error.
This is an image of the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you share `test.sh`?  I don't think it's possible to guess what went wrong.

Comment: Hey Jon! I already fixed it. I corrected the mistake form my jdl test file.

Comment: @ArmelHyacinthe, How did you fix? This would help others if they face the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same issue, and in my case it was the User entity that was used in the paginate option. Simply remove it and it will works !

Instead of doing:

```
paginate User, AnotherEntity with pagination
```

Do:

```
paginate AnotherEntity with pagination
```